# iterating through loops without using Regex

Tags: python, loops

```
lst = 'AB[CD]EF[GH]'
```

Output: ['A','B','CD','E','F','GH']

This is what I've tried but it's not working...

```
while(index < len(my_string)):
 curr_char = my_string[index]
 if(curr_char == '['):
      while(curr_char != ']'):
           multi = my_string[index + 1]
           index += 1
lst += multi
```

Can anybody please help? Without importing Regex or whatever. I wanna do this without using it.

Comment: You've just duplicated your own question with no clarification on what's wrong with the close vote on your last one.

Comment: @roganjosh true but this wasn't really a duplicate. I reopened the "original" one

Comment: That's fair enough. I did scan the duplicate and wasn't sure of relevance. I can't tag you on phone browser it seems to give you a notification. Thanks for closing this one though.

Comment: @roganjosh you did well by flagging that one. but the original question wasn't, so I understand OP frustration. He should have edited/pinged the people who closed (but he's new)

Comment: Thannk you for understanding Jean